# Transformar um texto em voz com SpeechSynthesis

Tags: javascript, html

### Estou tentando reproduzir um texto em áudio!

Era para exibir uma lista com as vozes e línguas (*Voz: Maria - Português "pt-BR", Voz: Anna - Inglês "en-US", **...***) selecionar a desejada, escrever um texto e assim reproduzi-la em áudio. Porém estou tendo problemas e sem sucesso para resolver!

```
<body>

    Selecionar Voz: <select id="voiceList"></select><br><br>
    <input id="txtInput" /><br><br>
    <button id="btnSpeak">Falar!</button>

    <script>
        // Selecionando as id do HTML
        var txtInput = document.querySelector('#txtInput')
        var voiceList = document.querySelector('#voiceList')
        var btnSpeak = document.querySelector('#btnSpeak')

        // sintetizador
        var synth = window.SpeechSynthesis;
        var voices = []

        NewVoices()
        if (speechSynthesis !== undefined) {
            speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = NewVoices     
        }

        btnSpeak.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var toSpeak = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(txtInput.value)
            var selectedVoiceName = voiceList.selectedOptions[0].getnAttribute('data-name')
            voices.forEach((voice) => {
                if (voice.name === selectedVoiceName) {
                    toSpeak.voice = voice
                }
            })

            synth.speak(toSpeak);
        })

        function NewVoices() {
            voices = synth.getVoices()
            var selectedIndex = voiceList.selectedIndex < 0 ? 0 : voiceList.selectedIndex
            voiceList.inneHTML= ''
            voices.forEach((voice) => {
                var listItem = document.createElement('option')
                listItem.textContent = voice.name
                listItem.setAttribute('data-lang', voice.lang)
                listItem.setAttribute('data-name', voice.name)
                voiceList.appendChild(listItem)
            })

            voiceList.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Já deu uma olhadinha nesse exemplo: https://github.com/rbmelolima/SpeechSynthesis ?

Comment: quais problemas você está tendo? apresente um [mcve]

Comment: Provável que seja nesta linha: `voiceList.selectedOptions[0].getnAttribute('data-name')` em `getnAttribute('data-name')` que está incorreta, seria `getAttribute('data-name')`

Answer (score 1):

### Ocorre devido a função `getnAttribute` está errada! o correto seria `getAttribute`

Apesar de necessariamente não precisar de uma resposta (*para fins futuros, fica ai a dica!*) e inclusive por falta de alguns detalhes importantes em sua pergunta, sugiro [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/522185/edit) ela e adicionar os critérios de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Vale muito apena dar uma olhada!

---

Antes de mais nada, veja [SpeechSynthesis - APIs da Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) suas **propriedades** e seus **suportes**, por se tratar de uma Tecnologia Experimental, torna-se empolgante! (*particularmente falando..*)

Fiz um pequeno código de "correção" sem a função `getAttribute` pois como mencionei acima, sua pergunta não está atendendo os devidos critérios. Por não saber onde se enquadra esta função, decidi criar o exemplo sem ela, abaixo:

```js
const synth = window.speechSynthesis; // chamada SpeechSynthesis API
const input = document.querySelector('input'); // caixa de texto
const selectVoices = document.querySelector('select'); // lista de vozes

let voices = [];
function getVoices() { 
  voices = synth.getVoices(); // armazena as vozes no array
  voices.forEach((voice, index) => {
    selectVoices.add(new Option(`${voice.name} (${voice.lang})`, index)); // adiciona as informações na lista de seleção..
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => { // ao ser concluído..
  getVoices(); // carrega as vozes..
  if (synth.onvoiceschanged !== undefined)
    synth.onvoiceschanged = getVoices; // checa e atualiza o evento
});

// dispara um evento ao clicar no botão!
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var utter = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(input.value); // responsável pelo que vai falar!
  utter.voice = voices[selectVoices.value]; // define qual será a voz..
  synth.speak(utter); // reproduz o audio!
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Insira o texto aqui.." />
<select></select>
<button>Fale!</button>
```

Comment: Funciona bem, dá para até para brincar com a *Siri*: `Oi Siiri, você está aí?`, mas não consigo selecionar a voz.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não consegue selecionar a voz? está por onde? mobile ou desktop?

Comment: Estou no desktop do windows 10, usando chrome. Print: https://imgur.com/a/F3Svqx3

Comment: Parece-me não ter suporte ainda no Chrome, estou no Edge 92 (*acredito eu ser uma classe nativa do browser ou implementada pela Microsoft*)

Comment: No Edge é mesmo, converte o texto em voz porém não é possível selecionar uma voz.

Comment: @AugustoVasques entranho! vou checar aqui em seguida retorno aqui.. altero o código da resposta!

Comment: Dá uma olha nessa página https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices no meu sistema tenho 50 vozes instaladas. Por essa página lista todas. Link do exemplo onde lista as vozes disponíveis no sistema https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices#example

Comment: @AugustoVasques tenta agora! até o momento, o problema era apenas atualizar o evento `onvoiceschanged` (o contrário do Edge que já faz isso automaticamente)